# Why does gcc optimize away this loop?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-optimization

Since 10.1, given this code:

```
extern int flag;
extern "C"
void wait() {
    while(flag);
}
int flag = 4;
```

g++ returns this assembly

```
wait:
        ret
flag:
        .long   4
```

Clang does it too!  Why is this allowed?  It seems clearly wrong.

Here it is on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/qeWGMGa87

Comment: Why wouldn't it?  It's not `atomic` or even `volatile`.  Well that explains hoisting the load, to make `if(flag) while(1){}` ([MCU programming - C++ O2 optimization breaks while loop](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/387478)).  But to optimize away that, too, infinite loops with no side effects or volatile accesses are UB in C++, so it can assume it terminates.

Comment: An infinite loop that has no observable behaviour gives undefined behaviour in C++.   An implementation can do anything it likes, including hanging the program, consuming all CPU resources, giving a diagnostic, not giving a diagnostic, electrocuting the programmer (rare in practice, otherwise the number of programmers would be seriously less than it is), or (as is happening in your case) optimising it away.